# I am trying to come up with a program to store user input (strings) in a vector and output them in descending order by length

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

An example would be.

Input:

```
Hey this is fantastic!
```

Output:

```
fantastic!
this
Hey
is
```

sorry if I haven't asked the question properly. This is all I have to go by.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `std::sort` function from `<algorithm>` and `std::vector<std::string>`.  There are plenty of examples on the internet on how to write a function that orders the strings by descending order (pass the function to `std::sort`).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) standard algorithm, giving it a predicate that sorts in descending order, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::string s;

    std::getline(std::cin, s);

    std::istringstream iss(s);
    while (iss >> s) {
        v.push_back(s);
    } 

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(),
        [](const std::string &a, const std::string &b){ return a.size() >= b.size(); }
    );

    for(auto &word: v) {
        std::cout << word << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/FL0Y3E)

Answer (score -1):

Check out the method reverse from std Library, this is an example I just found on Internet, it will reverse the order on the string vector you pass on it. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/